# Filtering XML elements by child node value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a feed with products, all the products have a child node called 'category' with a value. I can't find a way to return all products with a certain category value.

The XML looks something like this

```
<product>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <category>Category A</category>
</product>
<product>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <category>Category B</category>
</product>
<product>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <category>Category A</category>
</product>
<product>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <category>Category B</category>
</product>
<product>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <category>Category B</category>
</product>
```

I've tried looping through the XML, using PHP code like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

foreach ($xml as $product) {

    if ((string) $product['category'] == 'Category A') {
        echo (string) $product['name'];
    }

}
```

Expected outcome is to return/echo other child nodes for that product. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems sound, I'm not familiar enough with SimpleXML to say why it's not working. **But**, since you asked for the best approach, I'm partial to DomDocument and XPath myself:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>xxxx</name>
        <category>Category A</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>xxxx</name>
        <category>Category B</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>xxxx</name>
        <category>Category A</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>xxxx</name>
        <category>Category B</category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>xxxx</name>
        <category>Category B</category>
    </product>
</products>
XML;

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$search = "Category A";
$nodes = $xpath->query("//product[category='$search']/name");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    printf("%s\n", $node->textContent);
}
```

For SimpleXML, after a little digging it looks like it needs to access elements with object notation, not array notation. This worked for me:

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($x->product as $product) {
    if ((string) $product->category == 'Category A') {
        echo (string) $product->name;
    }
}
```

But I maintain that learning DOM and XPath methods will serve you better in the long run; they're both well established standards that are used in many languages. Knowledge about SimpleXML is not something you can transfer to another environment.